# How to log deadlocks for each database separately

Tags: mysql, mariadb, deadlock, logs

I have MariaDB 10.6.5 server with several databases.
I added a line innodb_print_all_deadlocks = 1 to config file.
Now all deadlocks are logged to one file /var/log/mysql/mariadb.err
Is there any way to split deadlocks to separate files for each database?
I need to split the log file to make a report for programer on which DB was deadlock and which tables.

Maybe there is a tool that could help me generate a report on which database occur dedadlock and which tables

Comment: Show us one of the deadlocks (`SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;`) and we will help you get rid of that one.  You may see a pattern that lets you fix most of the deadlocks.

Comment: There's no splitting of server log possible in server settings. Look at a logrotate or other server log processing framework for splitting the error messages.

Answer (score 3):

The fact that you want to log your Deadlocks separately by database suggests, to me, that you're seeing an *awful lot* of Deadlocks.

I would suggest that you'd be far better off finding out *why* the Deadlocks are happening in the first place and fix *that cause*, rather than just trying to keep on top of the *mess* that they're making of your logging system.

You should get *very few*, if any, Deadlocks in properly written Applications.

Comment: For now it refers to one database, but in future it could happen to the rest of databases. I need to split the log file to make a report for programer on which DB was deadlock and which tables.